# How to reference a previous iteration in a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm writing some code to draw 2 8 pixel long lines on a LCD end to end. I would like to do this using a for loop, however I am stuck working out how to connect the start of the second to the end of the first. The following code produces the pattern I am after, however is very repetitive when doing many lines:

```
void draw_road(){
    double angle = PI/2;
    double length = 8;
    int starting_x = 24;
    int starting_y = 48;
        double x1a = starting_x;
        double y1a = starting_y;
        double x2a = x1a + (cos(angle) * length);
        double y2a = y1a - (sin(angle) * length);
        draw_line(x1a, y1a, x2a, y2a, FG_COLOUR);
        double x1b = x2a ;
        double y1b = y2a;
        double x2b = x1b + (cos(angle-(angle/4.5)) * length);
        double y2b = y1b - (sin(angle-(angle/4.5)) * length);
        draw_line(x1b, y1b, x2b, y2b, FG_COLOUR);
}
```

I have tried the code below, however I don't think it knows where to look for [i-1].

```
 void draw_road(){
        double angle = PI/2;
        double length = 8;
        int starting_x = 24;
        int starting_y = 48;
        double x1[2];
        double y1[2];
        double x2[2];
        double y2[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            x1[i] = starting_x + x2[i-1];
            y1[i] = starting_y + y2[i-1];
            x2[i] = x1[i] + (cos(angle) * length);
            y2[i] = y1[i] - (sin(angle) * length);
            draw_line(x1[i], y1[i], x2[i], y2[i], FG_COLOUR);
            angle /= 2;
        }
    }
```

How can I correct this so the for loop knows the values of the last loop (especially if it is the very first loop)?

Comment: The first loop does not have a last (previous) loop, and your suggested replacement has more lines of code than what you want to replace. There is a boring side to C, as in any pursuit, and you have to get through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first iteration, you don't have a "previous" position; So there is no line to draw but just to declare the starting point.

An `if` around the call to `draw` and conditional operators for distinguishing between "setting a starting point" and "calculating the next point" could do the job:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    x1[i] = (i>0) ? starting_x + x2[i-1] : starting_x;
    ...
    if (i>0) {
        drawLine(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to add an if statement for when i == 0 at the start but that is all

Comment: Are you able to tell me what the use of the ? and : is called?